# jQuery: Cascading popups

Tags: jquery, popup, tooltip, show

I have the following code to display a pop-up div:

```
<a href="#" id="pop1" rel="div#tt1">Click to show popup</a>
<div class="popupBlock" id="tt1">My popup content ...</div>
```

The div is initially hidden and with a bit of jQuery code I'm turning it visible when pop1 anchor is clicked. This is the plgin I've made for this:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.pop = function(options) {


    var defaults = {
        show: "click",
        tooltip: null
    };
    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
    var target = $(this);
    var popup = $(target.attr("rel"));

    popup.css("visibility", "hidden").css("display", "none");
    target.click(function() {
        popup.css("visibility", "visible").css("display", "block");
        return false;
    });

    $('body').click(function() {
        popup.css("visibility", "hidden").css("display", "none");
        return false;
    });

    popup.click(function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
     });
};
```

All seems to be in order, but the whole thing breaks when I add a control in the div, such as:

```
<div class="popupBlock" id="tt1">My popup content ...
       <span> some text here</span>
</div>
```

The span doesn't trigger the div's click event and hides the div, which I don't want. 
Anyone has any idea what I need to be doing here to prevent this?
Thank you,
V

Answer (score 0):

```
var popup = $(target.attr("rel")).add($(target.attr("rel") > *));
```

or

```
var popup = $(target.attr("rel"), $(target.attr("rel") > *));
```